# Google Map not display on the Mobile Screen in Android

Tags: java, android

My error shows Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors). But wifi is working on phone. I have generated API Key of same application.

//MainActivity code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   
        map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
}
```

//activity_main.xml code is below :

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

//Menifest code is Below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gpslocator2222"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gpslocator2222.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <!-- permission  -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <permission
      android:name="com.example.gpslocator2222.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--Google MAP API key-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="xxxxxx"/>         
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: you sure the key from the console that you use in the manifest file has the package name in its authenticated packages ?

Comment: You should really not put your api key in a public site!